# Using a square image on a wide tile in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, image-scaling, live-tile

In my application I want to implement secondary tiles in order to let users access specific sections of my application directly and to show section specific information on that tile.

For tile image I want to use icon of the section that will be accessed directly, but I only have access to square-sized images which are downloaded directly from a web link (while creating the tile). As I don't have images for the wide tiles, I have tried to pad them with transparent borders in order to create a wide tile. I used WritableBitmapEx library but my code causes AccessViolationException.

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.GetFileAsync(tempFileName);
IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);                                              

WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(150, 150);
await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);

WriteableBitmap bitmapDummy = BitmapFactory.New(310, 150);

using (bitmapDummy.GetBitmapContext())
{
    using (bitmap.GetBitmapContext())
    {
        bitmapDummy.Blit(new Rect(80.0, 0.0, 150, 150), bitmap, new Rect(0.0, 0.0, 150, 150), WriteableBitmapExtensions.BlendMode.None);
    }
 }
```

the exception occurs on `bitmap.GetBitmapContext()` so I cannot create an image.

What I try to do here is to create an empty wide tile image and put the square tile image in the middle of it.

Also in the end I want to convert the image to transparent PNG but that is another problem as I can't work out how to create an bitmap yet.

Thanks for your helps in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109097/accessviolationexception-when-accessing-pixel-color-using-writeablebitmapex?rq=1). It seems that the image wasn't loaded into the WriteableBitmap before I tried to access it hence AccessViolationException was thrown. So instead of,

```
WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(150, 150);
await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
```

I started using,

```
WriteableBitmap bitmap = await BitmapFactory.New(1, 1).FromStream(fileStream);
```

and the problem is now solved.

The complete code that resizes and pads the square image for those who finds this question is below.

```
public static async Task PadPngImage(StorageFile inputFile, StorageFile outputFile, uint width, uint height, uint boundingBoxWidth, uint boundingBoxHeight)
{
    // Resize the input image
    StorageFile temporaryFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("PadImageTemporaryFile.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await ResizeImage(inputFile, temporaryFile, width, height);            

    // Create a stream linked to resized image
    using (IRandomAccessStream temporaryFileStream = await temporaryFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        WriteableBitmap bitmap = await BitmapFactory.New(1, 1).FromStream(temporaryFileStream);

        // Create an empty image with specified bounding dimentions
        WriteableBitmap bitmapDummy = BitmapFactory.New((int)boundingBoxWidth, (int)boundingBoxHeight);

        using (bitmapDummy.GetBitmapContext())
        {
            using (bitmap.GetBitmapContext())
            {
                // Calculate position of the image
                Rect center = new Rect((boundingBoxWidth - width) / 2, (boundingBoxHeight - height) / 2, width, height);

                bitmapDummy.Blit(center, bitmap, new Rect(0.0, 0.0, width, height), WriteableBitmapExtensions.BlendMode.None);                        
            }
        }

        using(IRandomAccessStream stream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            await bitmapDummy.ToStream(stream, BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId);
        }                
    }
}

public static async Task ResizeImage(StorageFile inputFile, StorageFile outputFile, uint newWidth, uint newHeight)
{
    // Input Stream & Decoder
    using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await inputFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(fileStream);

        // Output Stream & Encoder                
        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(stream, decoder);

            // Scale the bitmap image
            encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = newWidth;
            encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = newHeight;
            encoder.BitmapTransform.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Fant;

            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
}
```